# How to use the ruby time function in a method (if statement)?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, methods, time, return-value

Hi I'm doing this question and it is not passing the automated tests and would love to know where i'm going wrong? Many thanks.

question:
The hello function Should return (not puts)
'Good morning!' between 09:00 and 12:00 and
'Good afternoon!' between 12:00 and 16:00 and
'Hello!' at all other times

```
def hello
    t = Time 
    if t = (0900..1200)
        return 'Good morning!'
    elsif t = (1201..1600)
        return 'Good afternoon!'
    else
        return "Hello!"
    end
    
end
hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an assignment so I'll do my best to not just give the answer. There are a few misconceptions in your code and incorrect statements causing it to behave the way it is.

`t = Time` assigns the class `Time` to `t`, it does not generate a time. You can use `irb` or even on online [REPL](https://repl.it/languages/ruby) to learn more information about what a variable holds in realtime.

```
t = Time
t       #=> Time
t.class #=> Class
```

You should look into the ruby [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html) class, you'll be interested in the methods `#new`, `#now`, and potentially `#parse`.

Your if statement is not checking equality, it's assigning a range of integers to `t`. A range is a truthy value, so if the code ran the first conditionally would always be true. The range syntax is incorrect, the leading zero makes ruby think this number is an Octal, which only supports digits 0-7.

```
t = (0900..1200) #=> Error, it thinks 0900 is an invalid Octal
t = (900..1200)
t                #=> 900..1200
t.class          #=> Range
```

For this area you'll want to get more familiar with the difference between `=` assignment, and `==` equality. It's also worth noting that `integers` and `time` are *different classes*, so you cannot compare a raw time with a range of integers.

Fixing the time generation and time comparison should get you on the right path for passing tests.

Comment: This has been really helpful thank you! I'm for sure going to make sure I go over these basics to avoid making these mistakes in the future :)